# How to scale out NServiceBus on either end?

Tags: .net, msmq, nservicebus

I try to get the overview of how NServiceBus scales out in various scenarios, but I have failed to find sufficient information out there.

Generally, it seems that scaling out NServiceBus (and the underlying transport) is different in a pub/sub scenario, than in a send/receive scenario. Furthermore, it seems to play a difference whether the message emitting system(s) are scaled out or the "absorbing" systems are scaled out.

Consider a setting with MSMQ as transport layer and NServiceBus on top, and assume that we will use the queue, `MyQueue`, as communication channel from an emitting system to an absorbing system (either via send/receive or pub/sub). How would a scale-out setup look like in the following scenarios? I have tried coming up with some answers below, but am not sure.

- **Emitting system unscaled; absorbing system unscaled:** This is the trivial setup with one single endpoint at both ends, and one single queue at the receiver.

  Subscription storage at both systems: MSMQ
- **Emitting system unscaled; absorbing system scaled:** A single node at the absorbing system, the endpoint, is "promoted" as [Distributor](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scalability-and-ha/distributor/) and a number of worker nodes gets messages from that single distributor node.

  Does it make a difference if the absorbing system *subscribes* or *receives*?

  And can the distributor be scaled out as well?

  The [documentation](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scalability-and-ha/individualizing-queues-when-scaling-out) suggests using individual queue names, but isn't it messy if the sending/publishing systems should care about weather the receiving system is scaled out or not? From the sender's perspective, the receiver's scale-out should be transparent, I think.

  Subscription storage at both systems: MSMQ? Where *is* the subscription stored? At the distributor?
- **Emitting system scaled; absorbing system unscaled:** Multiple nodes at the emitting system can *send* to the unscaled absorbing system, just like in the unscaled/unscaled scenario above. But multiple nodes at the emitting system cannot (or should not) *publish* to the same absorbing system? Or what? How is *publish* from multiple nodes handled?

  Subscription storage at both systems: MSMQ?
- **Emitting system scaled; absorbing system scaled:** Is this just a combination of the above two cases for both the send/receive and pub/subscribe patterns?

  Subscription storage at both systems: MSMQ?

In short, it could be nice to get an overview of how the recommended NServiceBus setup for the above four cases.

Comment: Are you limited to MSMQ? NServiceBus supports other transports as well?

Comment: No, we are not limited to MSMQ, as such, but I like the distributed (i.e. broker less) nature of MSMQ. Also, as MSMQ comes with windows it matches our customer's desire to prioritize standard Microsoft components. Would you recommend something else, though?

Comment: There is the SQL Server transport if you want another option based on standard Microsoft software. That scales out by using the competing consumer pattern, avoiding the need for an explicit distributor completely.

Comment: @UdiDahan - the transport support in NServiceBus is pretty poor in my opinion. It's amazing to see that you don't support MQ out of the box. In an enterprise environment this is a major issue.

Comment: @Sean the approach we recommend is to have a simple bridge between MQ and whatever other transport you decide to use and have sample code showing how to do that. We came to this approach after trying to work with people running everything on MQ and saw all the difficulties it brought them.

Comment: @UdiDahan - That's a bit of a cop-out. When we contacted Particular.net about using MQ they pointed us at some MQ code on Github. However, it's 2 years old, unsupported, and doesn't build against nServiceBus 5. Backward compatibility in nServiceBus is really poor (the approach seems to be to just drop interafaces/classes/methods) so the Github code is useless.

Comment: @UdiDahan - Plus, if you want to have a go at trying to write your own transport then good luck. There's no formal documentation, so you have to ILSpy existing transports to work out how to do it, and it'll probably break in a later release when they change the API again!

Comment: @Sean I'm not sure that commenting here is the best place for us to have this discussion so I've created a GitHub issue to make this more visible and accessible: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2815

Comment: @Sean and on the topic of writing your own transport - yeah, I know that sucks. The internals of NServiceBus have been changing quite a lot, and that's been impacting the transports as well. The thing is that that will probably change at least one more time when async/await is factored into the framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all it's important to realize that the distributor component in NServiceBus is *ONLY relevant if you are scaling out the MSMQ transport.* The other supported transports are brokers and use the competing consumer pattern to achieve the same result.

Second you need to understand that **NServiceBus makes a distinction between a logical autonomous component/endpoint, and the physical deployment of it**. When you send, publish or subscribe you use the LOGICAL address of the endpoint ONLY. The logical address is often the same as the physical, but it does not have to be. There can be only one logical endpoint address for a service, but multiple physical deployments of it.

In a non-scaled scenario, it is the same thing. Let's say `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` are deployed to machine `Machine1`. The logical endpoint address and physical address for `ServiceA` would be `ServiceA@Machine1`. The logical address and physical address for ServiceB would be `ServiceB@Machine1`.

In a scaled out scenario, this would be different. Let's say you physically deploy `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` to `Machine1` and `Machine2`. You also deploy two distributors for `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` to a third machine, `MachineX`. `ServiceA` now has one logical endpoint address, `ServiceA@MachineX`, but two physical addresses: `ServiceA@Machine1` and `ServiceA@Machine2`. `ServiceB` also has one logical endpoint address, `ServiceB@MachineX`, and two physical addresses: `ServiceB@Machine1` and `ServiceB@Machine2`.

**Enter the distributor.** It is a simple load balancer. It takes incoming messages from the logical endpoint of a service and forwards them to one of the physical endpoints/workers. It will do this in a round robin-ish way to distribute the load.

The trick to making this work is always to use the logical endpoint address of the component you want to reach when you send, subscribe or publish something. Never directly use the physical address of individual endpoint deployments.

**Let's look at a simple send.** `ServiceA` wants to send something to `ServiceB`. One of the physical endpoints of `ServiceA`, on `Machine1`, will create a message and put it into the logical address for `ServiceB`, `ServiceB@MachineX`. The message contains both the physical and the logical endpoint address of the sender. The distributor for `ServiceB` on `MachineX` will pick up the message and hand it off to either `ServiceB@Machine1` or `ServiceB@Machine2`. That's it. That's all the distributor does.

**Subscriptions work the same way.** Say `ServiceA` wants to subscribe to one of `ServiceB`'s events. One of the physical endpoints of `ServiceA` sends a subscription message to the logical endpoint address for `ServiceB`, `ServiceB@MachineX`. The message essentially contains the following "`ServiceA` would like to subscribe to `event XXX`". The distributor picks up the subscription message and hands it over to either `ServiceB@Machine1` or `ServiceB@Machine2`. The lucky worker looks at the message and stores the fact that logical `ServiceA` would like to subscribe to `event XXX`. Note that it stores the logical endpoint address and NOT the endpoint address of the physical deployment of `ServiceA` that happened to send the subscription message. *The subscription storage belongs to the logical `ServiceB` endpoint and is shared between all the physical deployments of it. This rules out MSMQ as storage. The supported stores are NHibernate or RavenDB.* (A bit different for transports with native pub/sub-support, but that is beside the point.)

**Publish is similar.** `ServiceB` wants to publish the `XXX event`. One of the physical deployments of `ServiceB` looks into the subscription database for subscriptions to `event XXX`. It sees that logical endpoint address at `ServiceA@MachineX` is interested in that event. It then puts the event on that queue. The distributor for `ServiceA` on `MachineX` picks up the message and distributes it to one of the workers.

*The distributor itself can not be scaled out*, but it becomes a single point of failure if you don't make it highly available. [The recommendation is to use a Windows Failover Cluster](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scalability-and-ha/deploying-to-a-windows-failover-cluster)  for the distributors and their MSMQ.

There is also the concept of the MasterNode. Look at it as Distributor and a Worker running in the same physical process to optimize resource usage on the machines hosting the Windows Failover Cluster. All the above still applies for the MasterNode.

Comment: What an elaborate answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have the ability to add a Worker node to any NServiceBus endpoint.  A choice that has to be made is whether or not the Master node also processes messages or not.  Depending on your scenario, you may chose either.  The Distributor role is used in the scenario where the Master node is not processing messages, but is acting as a dispatcher.

The primary difference in using Send vs. Publish is the dependency on Subscription storage.  When Publishing you require an external storage mechanism and this storage must be queried on every Publish in the event there are new subscribers.  This has an overhead associated with it.  When Publishing you should subscribe via the Master node and it will determine if it will process the messages or not based on the configuration described above.

When scaling out a Publisher, the Master and Worker will both speak to the Subscription storage and perform the publishing in a round robin like fashion.  The Master node is made aware of whether or not the Workers are busy and the load will be distributed accordingly.

If the messages being exchanged are not of any interest to other endpoints you may consider sticking with point to point communication (Send) to eliminate the overhead associated with Publishing.